# Virtual IP configuration doesn't work, I still get a address already in use error

Tags: linux, perl, sockets, bind

I created `eth3:1, eth3:2, eth3:3` with 3 different virtual ip address in a virtual machine,

Now I'm trying to create more than 65k connections to a nginx server running at `192.168.56.1`.

As the resource in VM is limited, so I reduced port range by

> sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="32768 33000"

Then I try to create `600` threads, that would send a request (`GET / HTTP/1.1`) to the nginx server (`running at 192.168.56.1`) 200 times with each virtual ip addresses.

But my program fails somwehere! IO::Socket tells me `address in use`.

So I checked my nginx log, it only used 2 different ip addresses (`192.168.56.23 and 192.168.56.24`) to access the nginx server, and the total count is only 233 (`expected 200 x 3 = 600 access logs`).

Anyone know what's going wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use threads;
use IO::Socket::INET;

$| = 1;

sub run
{
        my ($ip, $id) = @_;
        print ">> Sendto .. $ip ($id)\n";

        my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
                PeerHost  => '192.168.56.1',
                LocalHost => $ip,
                PeerPort  => '80',
                Proto     => 'tcp',
        ) or die $@;

        print $socket "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
        sleep (100); # hold connection
        $socket->close();
}

my @threads = ();
my @ips = qw/192.168.56.23 192.168.56.24 192.168.56.25/;

foreach my $ip (@ips)
{
        for (1..200)
        {
                push @threads, threads->create (\&run, $ip, $_);
        }
}

$_->join for @threads;
```

Comment: To whoever hit on close, what's wrong with it? Leave a comment please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm that Linux uses for finding a free local port doesn't care about the local IP address, so the range of ports is *shared* between all the IPs. This blog post discusses the problem further:
http://aleccolocco.blogspot.com/2008/11/ephemeral-ports-problem-and-solution.html

A possible solution is to set the local port manually:

```
    my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
            PeerHost  => '192.168.56.1',
            LocalHost => $ip,
            LocalPort => 32768 + $id,
            PeerPort  => '80',
            Proto     => 'tcp',
    ) or die $@;
```